# How to (.htaccess) rewrite the url of a specific search query?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I wish to (.htaccess) rewrite the url of a search query when it has the "custom_title" parameter. Anyone can help me? I'd like to rewrite this url:

`http://www.mysite.com/search.php?search_query=myquery&custom_title=mytitle`

to this:

`http://www.mysite.com/results/myquery/mytitle/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^results/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?search_query=$1&custom_title=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. I was wondering the difference between that (.+) below and your ([^/]+)...

Comment: `(.+)` can be non-greedy and may grab full input while `([^/]+)` is negation based regex that is guaranteed to stop at `/`

Comment: Last doubt: this code goes into my PrestaShop .htaccess that has already few rewrite rules all ending with: [QSA,L,E]. Is it better than [L,NC,QSA]?

Comment: Yes you don't need `E` flag for this rule at least. E is for setting env: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_e

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

`RewriteRule ^/results/(.+)/(.+)/$ /search.php?search_query=$1&custom_title=$2`

Then accessing URL http://www.mysite.com/results/myquery/mytitle/ in your browser will actually call your `search.php` file.