# Rewrite rule for HTML parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I'm struggling about how to setup .htaccess for getting the following url paramaters:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^search/([^/\.]+)/?$ /search/index.html?q=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

so, the goal is that when the URL is: mydomain.com/search/some+query the index.html within the search directory can get "some+query" as a parameter.

Any idea?

Comment: [Please refer below link and try](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445785/how-to-htaccess-rewrite-the-url-of-a-specific-search-query)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in root directory,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^search/([\w-]+)$ /search/index.html?q=$1 [QSA,NC,l]
```